# Need to make "slideshow" with bootstrap's list-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i got bootstrap's linked list-group (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked). When link is clicked, some js action is performed.

[Image of my list-group with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcWo7.png)

And what i need to do:
I have 3 buttons (go back, play, go forward). Play button should "click" links one by one after 1 second.

What will be the best way to do this? Is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need only with jQuery.
You should have a look at the `trigger` function. This function simulates events like `click`. You can find documentation [there](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

To trigger the click action every 1 second you'll have to use the `setInterval`function. Documentation [there](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).